# Visual Studio TFS Workspaces for website development

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017

We have a small number of web developers running Visual Studio 2017 configured with TFS as the source control system. The code is hosted on a network share \\wbserver\path and we have setup the TFS workspaces to use that path as the local folder as well, is this correct?

We did this so that we could check out the files, make changes and then test them on the website without having to check them in again but we are encountering issues where a file checked out by one user can still be edited by other users even though the checkout cannot occur.

The workspace settings are:

```
Computer: LOCALCOMPUTER
Location: Server
File Time: Current
Permissions: Private workspace
Local Folder: \\wbserver\path
```

We have removed multiple check-out from the TFS settings as well.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workspace is your local copy of the source, where you can work isolated from others until you're ready to check that source code in. Sharing a workspace is pretty much defeating that premise. If each developer has their own workspace, you won't have the problems you're referencing. The workspace can be on the developer's local system or a file share, but each dev should have their own workspace. As for testing, each developer should have an IIS instance where they can check the changes locally before checking in to the source code repository.